# Xamarin AutoSuggestBox Selected Item as Command Parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin

My panelists ask me if I can put an auto-suggestion in my application. After some research, I've decided to use this [AutoSugggestionBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox?view=winrt-22621) and followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4sDHPzuegQ) tutorial. However, I am having a hard time displaying the selected suggestion since I am converting it into an MVVM. In timestamp 16:12, he uses the `dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs` parameter to get the ChoseSuggestion.

My question is, what will I put in the `CommandParameter` if I use `xct:XamarinCommunityTools EventToCommandBehavior`

```
<control:AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Enter" 
                x:Name="AutoSuggestBox">
    <control:AutoSuggestBox.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted"
                                    Command="{Binding quesrySubmitComm}"
                                    CommandParameter=""
    </control:AutoSuggestBox.Behaviors>
</control:AutoSuggestBox>
```

Or is there a more simplified way to MVVMify an AutoSuggestBox?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on João's suggestions to use SuggestionChosen, I managed to get a work around with the MVVM

This is in my view

```
<control:AutoSuggestBox x:Name="box">
    <control:AutoSuggestBox.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                                    .../>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SuggestionChosen"
                                    Command="{Binding showComm}"
                                    CommandParameter="{x:Reference box}"/>
   </control:AutoSuggestBox.Behaviors>
</control:AutoSuggestBox>
```

And this is in my ViewModel

```
public ICommand showComm { get; }
private async Task show(object sender)
{
    AutoSuggestBox input = (AutoSuggestBox)sender;
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", input.Text, "OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SuggestionChosen for this!

You don't need this command.

Try this.

```
<control:AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Enter" 
                        x:Name="AutoSuggestBox"
                        SuggestionChosen="SuggestionChosen"/>
```

Create the method and get the chosen.